# How to send PHP array by html form by POST type

Tags: php, javascript, html, arrays, post

I am trying to send PHP array by html form by POST. The code which I am using is below:

```
<?php
    $content = array('111', '222' );
?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>PAGE TITLE</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <form name="downloadexcel" action="downloadexcel.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="data" value="<?php echo $content; ?>"/>
                <a href="javascript: submitform()">Download</a>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function submitform()
                {
                  document.downloadexcel.submit();
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

How can I send an PHP array by html form?

Any web link or source code would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you try to achieve but the best way to send arrays is serialization (I think better practice is to use [`json_encode`](http://tw.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)/[`json_decode`](http://tw.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)).

Comment: Why some one put negative marking of this question? Can any body tell me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send array like this. It will return `Array`. You can do it this way

```
<form name="downloadexcel" action="downloadexcel.php" method="post">

<?php foreach ($content as $item): ?>
    <input type="text" name="data[]" value="<?php echo $item; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach ?>

<a href="javascript: submitform()">Download</a>
</form>
```

This variant is the most elegant to use in templates or anywhere in the code. `HTML` will be easily validated by `IDE` and `code assist` will be also available.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$content = array('111', '222' );
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>PAGE TITLE</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form name="downloadexcel" action="downloadexcel.php" method="post">
            <?php foreach($content as $c) { ?>
               <input type="text" name="data[]" value="<?php echo $c; ?>"/>
            <?php }  ?>
            <a href="javascript: submitform()">Download</a>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitform()
            {
              document.downloadexcel.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's is an simple example:

```
$content = array('111', '222');

foreach($content as $c)
{
    echo "<input name='arr[]' value='{$c}'>";
}
```

You could alternatively use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to send the values.