# PHP send arrays through GET

Tags: php, arrays, get

I know I should be able to create arrays through GET by creating a url such as

```
?sort[]=four&sort[price]=five&sort[status]=good
```

and receive

```
$_GET['sort'] = ['four','price'=>'five','status'=>'good'];
```

but instead, when trying to access `$_GET['sort']` I get an undefined index for 'sort' and the only keys for $_GET are `'sort[]', 'sort[price]', 'sort[status]'`.

What do I need to change to make this work as expected?

Comment: I would advice looking into this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763508/passing-arrays-as-url-parameter/1764199#1764199

Comment: why you use same get parameter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send PHP array by html form by POST type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684274/how-to-send-php-array-by-html-form-by-post-type)

Comment: print_r($_GET['sort']); is working fine for me.

Comment: @thefolenangel I actually attempted that solution prior to asking the question and the keys for GET in that case are 
`'sort%5B0%5D'`, so essentially the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET query string is correctly parsed by PHP on my machine so I don't think there is anything wrong with your syntax.

What you can do as a workaround is manually parse the query string and populate `$_GET`

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```

`$_GET` is now:

```
[
  'sort' => [
      0        => 'four',
      'price'  => 'five',
      'status' => 'good',
  ],
]
```

Comment: This worked. clearly something is overriding how the variables are being parsed that I need to find and adjust. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`"http://example.com?".http_build_query(['four','price'=>'five','status'=>'good'])`

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: this works for sending individual keys which I wasn't having problems with before, but this method still doesn't work for what I am trying to do, which is

`"http://example.com?".http_build_query(['sort'=>['four','price'=>'five','status'=>'good']])`.

gives me `$_GET['sort%5B0%5D' => 'four',...]` etc

Comment: See example 3 on docs page. If that still does not work with GET, you can try to parse the query string by yorself. See parse_str